# How to use window.Function() instead of eval() in the code below?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to make a calculator recently and have discovered many tutorials on YouTube.

After going through many tutorials, I found a [tutorial](https://youtu.be/QS6Y0ezhyCs) that used a simple way and it was through the use of jQuery. It involved the use of eval() which I learnt is slow and has high risk when it comes to malicious malware.

I looked at this [webpage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!) and learned that window.Function() is better than eval(). I tried looking at some examples to make changes to the code but the examples provided are effective in other scenarios or is too confusing for me to understand.

Below is the JavaScript code:

```
let display=document.getElementById('display');
    let buttons=Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('button'));
    
    buttons.map(button=> {
        button.addEventListener('click',(e)=> {
            switch(e.target.innerText) {
                case 'C':
                    display.innerText='';
                    break;
                case '←':
                    if(display.innerText) {
                        display.innerText=display.innerText.slice(0,-1);
                    }
                    break;
                case '=':
                    try {
                        display.innerText=eval(display.innerText);
                    } catch {
                        display.innerText='Error';
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    display.innerText+=e.target.innerText;
            }
        });
    });
```

Please help me change eval() to window.Function() or recommend a better alternative than eval() for this scenario so I can learn to apply it in the future as well.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It's not that much better than `eval`. If you really want to do it properly, you need to write  parser and an interpreter for mathematical expressions.

Comment: @Bergi I'm a beginner in JavaScript so I don't understand terms like parser and interpreter. I tried searching online and it made me more confused so can you explain in a way where a novice can understand.